# Does final blow affect drops in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does the quality and rare rate when an item drops change due to whom gets the final blow?

Answer (score 4):

No, the drop rate is not dependent on who actually lands the final blow.

Diablo 3 does not use the same magic find as Diablo 2 did. They used to use all kinds of things like magic find % on items, increased magic find for solo players...etc. Now, they use a group-magic find increase - if you are close enough to other players the more your magic find is increased. All magic find is shared and is a % based on your difficulty that you are currently playing + your group magic find bonus.

All magic find on items are gone. It is impossible for someone else in your game to have a higher % magic find unless you are too far away from everyone else to lose the group-magic find bonus. You can see when it is enabled by an icon on your hotbar.

Comment: In D2, only the magic find of the player landing the final blow counted, so the answer would be yes. I can't find a definitive statement on whether this has changed in D3 so that it works for the whole party, but I would find that surprising.

Comment: Ive always assumed your magic find % dictates the rate of your Legendary drops, not quality or rate for the party, since loot is player-specific. E.g. my friend has higher magic find %, so in a regular rift, he consistently gets more random legendaries, like from a chest, or a loose tile, etc. When we both get a legendary from same situation, it seems random who has the better item. Cant find any authoritative post though either, sorry

Comment: @Dpeif Haven't played D3 in quite some time. Completely forgot the loot was player-specific. In that case it would make some sense for it to act like you were the one who got the final blow on everything.

Comment: @ChaseC That's all useful information that would be better in the answer.

Comment: @DCShannon Good point, added

Comment: The group buff is binary. Either you are close enough to have it, or you don't. It does not increase "the closer you are to other players"

Comment: @Dallium You are correct, I have no idea why I worded it that way. Changed.

Comment: @ChaseC It's been a while since I logged on did they remove the gem that gives bonus item find as well?

Comment: @Puddler Yes, everything with bonus item find on any items is gone.